# Const variable returns two different values

Tags: rust

Today I did some tests on the nightly module `std::lazy`. It works well in **local** variable. However, when I defined a **`const`** variable, it gave me two different values. Seems the Colsure is called multiple times.

```rust
#![feature(once_cell)]
use rand::Rng; // 0.8.4
use std::lazy::Lazy;

const CONST_LAZY: Lazy<i32> = Lazy::new(|| rand::thread_rng().gen::<i32>());

fn main() {
    let local_lazy: Lazy<i32> = Lazy::new(|| rand::thread_rng().gen::<i32>());
    println!("{}", *local_lazy); // -1475423855
    println!("{}", *local_lazy); // -1475423855

    println!("{}", *CONST_LAZY); // 1975106939
    println!("{}", *CONST_LAZY); // -1848043613
}
```

Comment: `const` is a bit weird in Rust, because it basically means that the initialization expression gets inlined at the use site. So each use gets its own Lazy with its own closure. You should report a bug, though, because for `Lazy` this behavior is extremely counter-intuitive.

Comment: Clippy reports this "a `const` item should never be interior mutable".

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thanks for your advice. I've reported this "bug".

Comment: @RustySpotted Out of curiosity, do you have a link to the issue?

Comment: @Caesar [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74465#issuecomment-995378607) Seems `lazy` is not designed for this usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is my code, can anyone tell me why?

Because you're confusing `const` and `static`.

Per [the official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html):

> A *constant item* is an optionally named [*constant value*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#constant-expressions) which is not associated with a specific memory location in the program. Constants are essentially inlined wherever they are used, meaning that they are copied directly into the relevant context when used. This includes usage of constants from external crates, and non-`Copy` types. References to the same constant are not necessarily guaranteed to refer to the same memory address.

(note that the phrasing of the last sentence indicates consts *could* be promoted to statics and share a memory address, but there's no guarantee there, and while statics can be inlined it probably should not be observable through safe rust so should mostly be irrelevant).

In essence, your snippet is semantically equivalent to:

```rust
#![feature(once_cell)]
use rand::Rng; // 0.8.4
use std::lazy::Lazy;

fn main() {
    let local_lazy: Lazy<i32> = Lazy::new(|| rand::thread_rng().gen::<i32>());
    println!("{}", *local_lazy);
    println!("{}", *local_lazy);

    println!("{}", *Lazy::new(|| rand::thread_rng().gen::<i32>()));
    println!("{}", *Lazy::new(|| rand::thread_rng().gen::<i32>()));
}
```

That is also why it compiles at all, as `Lazy` is not thread-safe, and thus an actual global (a `static`) will not compile as it *could* be shared between threads.

Comment: Note you can use `std::lazy::SyncLazy` which _is_ thread-safe.

Comment: @Masklinn Your are right. The behavior of `const` is more complicated than I thought. According to the official documentation, is it necessary to implement the `Copy` trait for `Lazy` to meet my requirement?

Comment: @RustySpotted no, `const` does not care about `Copy` because -- as noted -- the entire thing gets inlined, so at each use site you're getting a copy of the init expression. That is explicitely documented in the snippet I pasted above. And the behaviour of `const` is not complicated (though the name is somewhat confusing), just think of it as a trivial replacement macro. It's not a *global constant*, it's an *initialisation constant*, like a literal.